# MySQL, Before start of resultset

Tags: java, mysql

I am getting the error **Before start of result set** I thought that I had to use next() on the ResultSet before retrieving data from the ResultSet ?

```
public void getPersonsOrders(String firstName){
    Connection con = connect();                                                                                             
    try{
        Statement s = con.createStatement();
        s.executeUpdate("use stl;");
        ResultSet rs1 = s.executeQuery("select personID from person where first_name = " +"'"+firstName+"'"+";");       //get persons ID no.
        ResultSet rs2 = s.executeQuery("select * from orderr where personID = "+rs1.getInt(1)+";");             //use ID no. to 
        rs2.next();
        for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++){                                                                             //retrive order
            System.out.println(rs2.getInt(i));
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("3" +e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: `ResultSet.next()` returns a boolean to indicate if there is a next row: check it.

Comment: Even when I delete that call I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you share the complete stack trace?

Comment: maybe there is no data returned

Comment: @JohnCollins : You always have to call `ResultSet.next()`, but if there are no rows, then you can't get values.

Comment: Just an aside, it looks like you could concatenate your two queries into a single query with a join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should execute

```
rs1.next();
```

before

```
ResultSet rs2 = s.executeQuery("select * from orderr where personID = "+rs1.getInt(1)+";");
```

Remember that you should close opened resources.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following mechanism.

```
resultSet=s.executeQuery("select personID from person where first_name = " +"'"+firstName+"'"+";");

            if (resultSet!= null)
            {

                do
                {
                   //You can code your business logic here by getting data from db like:

                 System.out.println(resultSet.getString("first_name"));
                } while (resultSet.next());
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't call `rs1.next()` before reading from it with `rs1.getInt(1)`.

As an aside, you can do this with a single SQL statement with a `join` are follows:

```
SELECT orderr.* FROM orderr JOIN person ON orderr.personID = person.personID WHERE person.first_name = ?
```

You should also use a [java.sql.PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) like this:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT orderr.* FROM orderr JOIN person ON orderr.personID = person.personID WHERE person.first_name = ?");
preparedStatement.setString(1, firstName);

ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

The database will cache the query plan, which will help performance plus it will prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I get a MySQL error with that statement.

Comment: It's looks like it should work, I obviously can't run it because I don't have your database, what's the error?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order.* FROM order JOIN person ON order.personID = person.personID WHERE person.' at line 1

Comment: ahh hang on its because the table is actually called 'orderr' mysql won't let me create a table called 'order'.

Comment: Your table was spelt `orderr` in your example, I'd assumed that was a typo - it that the case?

Comment: Comments crossed in mid-air.  Of course, `order` is a reserved word :-)  I've corrected it in my answer.

Comment: No mySQL won't does'nt allow you to create a table called 'order' - it is a preserved word.